# When is prepareForSegue called for embedded viewController?

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a tableViewController embedded inside a viewController. The thing is that I want to pass on some UITextFields value inside prototype cells of the tableViewController into the main viewController. My strategy is to use prepareForSegue to get to all the stuffs in the tableViewController.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DiveGearDetail"]) {
        DiveGearDetailTableViewController *DGTVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        gear_name = DGTVC.nameLabel.text;
        NSLog(@"Gear name: %@", gear_name);
    }
}
```

Is this a good strategy? When would this method get called after the viewDidLoad?

Comment: Are you getting Gear Name in Log?

Answer (score 1):

First write in tableview's didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DiveGearDetail" sender:nil];
```

This method will call prepareForSegue and you can assign value you want to assign in target class Like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DiveGearDetail"]) {
        DiveGearDetailTableViewController *DGTVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        DGTVC.gear_name = @"Your value"; // OR [[segue destinationViewController] setYourObject:value];
        NSLog(@"Gear name: %@", gear_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have never used tableviewDidSelect before. Where should I call this method?

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{} It is tableview's method like numberOfRowsInSection,cellForRowAtIndexPath...

Comment: OK, now I see what you mean. The thing is that I want to transfer the value from tableViewCells into the viewController that house the tableViewController. Not sure how triggering the segue via tableViewDidSelectRowAtIndexPath would help with the issue. However, now the seems that the somehow the prepareForSegue gets called after viewDidLoad, though...

Comment: YEs. Definitely. It's called after viewDidLoad.

Comment: The other person didn't accept your response, but it helps me so +1